# Disable indentation in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have disabled auto-indent in Notepad++ but it is still indenting. How do I turn indentation off?

[image]

Comment: Works as expected here with NP++ 7.4.2 (32-bit, on Windows 10 64-bit). You're MISC preference page looks like an older version, you should try an updated version of NP++.

Comment: It is an existing file of type normal text. (BTW I cannot @ your name because it has an untypable character in it)

Comment: If you just type the at you should already get a suggestion. Changing that option would only do something for new lines you're adding and not change the formatting of an existing file. I assume you're aware but just in case.

Answer (score 1):

settings>preferences>editing

set the line wrap radio button to "default" instead of "aligned"

Answer (score 0):

For my version of Notepad++ (8.2.1), go to Settings>Preferences>Auto-Completion, and un-check the Auto-indent check box.

I can't comment on the validity of Noah C's answer for other versions.